# CriteriaQuery no ordering

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I try to order by one field, but I see in sql-debugger that sql doesn't contain order-clause.

My code for Criteria is

```
GenericDaoImpl<T> {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = getCriteriaQuery(cb);
    Root<T> entity = getRoot(cq);
    cq.select(entity);
    TypedQuery<T> q = em.createQuery(cq);

    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(entity.get(order)));
```

And

```
public class GenericDaoClient extends GenericDaoImpl<Client> {
    @Override
    protected CriteriaQuery<Client> getCriteriaQuery(CriteriaBuilder cb){
            return (CriteriaQuery<Client>) cb.createQuery(Client.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected Root<Client> getRoot(CriteriaQuery cq){
            return cq.from(Client.class);
    }
```

Than I call my dao to get ordered list:

```
dao.findAll(false,page*step+1,(page-1)*step+1,"conferm");
```

As a result my sql-query doesn't have order clause:

```
select client0_.idCl as idCl218_ ... from Client client0_ limit ?, ?
```

Comment: What are the annotation used in `Client` class?

Comment: This problem is unrelated to JSF and RichFaces.

Comment: It is also unrelated to Hibernate.  This is generic JPA.  Hibernate may (or may not) be your provider, but the Criteria Queries you are writing are simply based on JPA - nothing Hibernate specific.

Answer (score 0):

You construct the typed query *before* setting the order by clause. Inverse these two instructions:

```
TypedQuery<T> q = em.createQuery(cq);
cq.orderBy(cb.asc(entity.get(order)));
```